# d3 Inverse & standard bar graph appearance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to have an standard and inverse bar graph conjoined. The way I went about it currently is creating two separate graphs then going to align the bottom of one and the top of the other. The issue is I can't seem to get them aligned correctly. I'm sure there's a better way to go about this. I thought about parsing one of the data amounts into negative numbers then displaying the positive number on the screen. This direction would involve stacking the bars first and foremost which I can do. I just am not sure how to create the negative space for positive data values, which is why I am doing the two separate graphs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 Example</title>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>

  .axis text {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
  .axis .label {
    font-size: 20pt;
  }

  .x.axis path, .x.axis line {
    stroke-width:2;
    stroke: #EBEBED; 
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
    .x.axis text{ font-weight: 500; transform:translate(0px,14px);stroke:#c7c7c7}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
 var outerWidth = 500;
  var outerHeight = 120;
  var margin = { left: 90, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 0 };
  var barPadding = 0.2;

  var xColumn = "date";


    var yColumn = "amount";

  var colorColumn = "barv";
  var layerColumn = colorColumn;

  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;



  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  var yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight,0]).nice();
  var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["top"])
        .range([ "#43B365" ])





  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0).ticks(0).tickSize(0);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(0)
    .outerTickSize(0);

  function render(data){

    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data)

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
      .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

    var layers = stack(nested);

    xScale.domain( data.map( function (d){ return d[xColumn]; }));

    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
    ]);

    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
      return layer.key;
    }));

    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    var layerGroups = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layerGroups.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layerGroups.exit().remove();
    layerGroups.style("fill", function (d){
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });

    var bars = layerGroups.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
      return d.values;
    });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars
      .attr("x", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()*.2)
      .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })
      .attr("ry", 2);

      var texty = g.selectAll("text.bar").data(data);
    texty.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.amount) - 10; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.amount; });  
  }

  var data = [
    {
      "date": "5/1/16",
      "amount": 1098,
      "barv": "top"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/8/16",
      "amount": 30,
      "barv": "top"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/16/16",
      "amount": 2504,
      "barv": "top"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/24/16",
      "amount": 560,
      "barv": "top"
    }
  ];

  render(data);


    //*****SECOND PART

    var outerWidth = 500;
  var outerHeight = 100;
  var margin = { left: 90, top: -10, right: 30, bottom: 40 };
  var barPadding = 0.2;

  var xColumn = "date";

    var yColumn = "amount";

  var colorColumn = "barv";
  var layerColumn = colorColumn;

  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;



  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  var yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0,innerHeight]).nice();
  var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["bot"])
        .range(["#DA5A60" ])




  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0).ticks(0).tickSize(0);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(0)
    .outerTickSize(0);

  function renders(data){

    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data)

    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
      .values(function (d){ return d.values; });

    var layers = stack(nested);

    xScale.domain( data.map( function (d){ return d[xColumn]; }));

    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(data, function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
    ]);

    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
      return layer.key;
    }));

    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);

    var layerGroups = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layerGroups.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layerGroups.exit().remove();
    layerGroups.style("fill", function (d){
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });

    var bars = layerGroups.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
      return d.values;
    });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars
      .attr("x", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand()*.2)
     .attr("height", function (d){ return   yScale(d[yColumn]); })
      .attr("ry", 2);


      var texty = g.selectAll("text.bar").data(data);
    texty.enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.date); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.amount) - 10; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.amount; }); 
  }

  var data = [
    {
      "date": "5/1/16",
      "amount": 34,
      "barv": "bot"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/8/16",
      "amount": 12,
      "barv": "bot"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/16/16",
      "amount": 47,
      "barv": "bot"
    },
    {
      "date": "5/24/16",
      "amount": 11,
      "barv": "bot"
    }
  ];

  renders(data);


</script>
</body>
```

Here are a few resources I have tried to implement but with no success. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/philgyford/LjxaV/2/
    http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/tNdJj/4/
    http://jsfiddle.net/5hzxegxx/2/
    http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/601c66edfb83a11cf2bb
Thanks

**UPDATE** I updated the code. I was able to figure out the alignment issue and the text appearing. The only issue is the tick labels are not aligned correctly to the bars and there is still space in between graphs.

Comment: Are you and @NicholasKyriakides in computer science class together?

Comment: Why? I don't know who that is

Comment: Exact same questions a minute after each other